# xboard using gnuchess does not work

Tags: 20.04

I am running Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS.  Both xboard and gnuchess are installed.  When I start xboard (with -fcp gnuchess option) it is good for one move only, and it dies on the second move.  There is a message printed to the command-line which says "=: Command not found".  Also, the Linux "ps" command shows gnuchess with "Z", i.e. a Zombie process.

Do you know what I might be doing wrong?  If so, please help.  Thank you.